# Angular Material 16: Chip text with overflow

Tags: css, angular-material

I have in some texts of a `Chip` some very long texts.  I have as well a button on the end of the `chip` to remove the chip.

I thought I can apply `text-overflow: ellipsis` for the text but somehow this doesn't help.

Currently it looks in my [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tc5xcb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-overview-example.html) like

[image]

but I want to have look like

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a **fixed width** was not an option for me as the interface needed to be **fluid**.

So I did some digging into the source code and found that the **chip text label** already has the CSS rules needed for truncating text, but this behaviour is overwritten for some reason

(*the details and code references are below the solution*):

---

**Solution**

As a workaround, we have to overwrite the rules, by the following css provided at:

a) **at component level**:

```scss
:host ::ng-deep .mdc-evolution-chip-set__chips {
  max-width: 100%;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-standard-chip .mdc-evolution-chip__cell--primary,
:host ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-standard-chip .mdc-evolution-chip__action--primary,
:host ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-standard-chip .mat-mdc-chip-action-label {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Example** - Parent container that takes all the screen width: https://stackblitz.com/edit/tc5xcb-fvpbyu

**Example** - Parent container with fixed width: https://stackblitz.com/edit/tc5xcb-yfytxs

**OR**

b) in **global** `styles.css` file:

```scss
.mdc-evolution-chip-set__chips {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}

.mat-mdc-standard-chip .mdc-evolution-chip__cell--primary,
.mat-mdc-standard-chip .mdc-evolution-chip__action--primary,
.mat-mdc-standard-chip .mat-mdc-chip-action-label {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

**Example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/tc5xcb-jrdkjw

---

**Details**

```scss
.mdc-evolution-chip__text-label {
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

(the code is in https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/v14.0.0/packages/mdc-chips/_chip.scss#L215):

But the behaviour is overwritten in **Angular Material** source code (**v16.0.2**), https://github.com/angular/components/blob/16.0.2/src/material/chips/chip.scss#L131:

```scss
// MDC sets `overflow: hidden` on these elements in order to truncate the text. This is
// unnecessary since our chips don't truncate their text and it makes it difficult to style
// the strong focus indicators so we need to override it.

.mdc-evolution-chip__cell--primary,
.mdc-evolution-chip__action--primary,
.mat-mdc-chip-action-label {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

---

There is also an issue opened on Github - https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26584.

I will follow up on this and update the answer accordingly when the issue gets resolved.

Comment: Thx for the link to the Github

Answer (score 1):

Ellipsis works if:

- the element's `width` is set in `px` and
- the element has `overflow: hidden;` and `white-space: nowrap;`.

See the [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tc5xcb-e1aetm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-overview-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchips-overview-example.css).

**HTML:**

```
<div class='sample-list'>
   <mat-chip-listbox aria-label="Fish selection">
      <mat-chip-option>
         <div class="clip-text">
            Just one fish with some very very long tail
         </div>
         <button matChipRemove>
            <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
         </button>
      </mat-chip-option>
   </mat-chip-listbox>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sample-list {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 205px;
}

.clip-text {
  width: 159px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thx for the response. It works although I have no clue how to set the width but nevertheless I have something to start with. Thx.